# What tools can be use to continuously monitor web application performance in the CI/CD pipeline

Tags: performance, jmeter, microservices

What are the best tools available to continuously evaluate web performance in a CI/CD pipeline like Drone, and notify about any performance drops.

I have a microservice based application, that I need to implement continuous performance monitoring

Comment: Off topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best" tool, you need to answer the following questions:

1. What are the [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) used by your application. The tool has to support all of them in order to be able to mimic real life usage of the application
2. Can the tool be executed in unattended command-line non-GUI mode
3. Can the tool produce the results which can be interpreted by the continuous integration server so it could fail the build automatically in case of performance degradation

Given you have [jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter) in your question tags take a look at [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) and [Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) which can mark the build as unstable or failed by comparing the metrics and KPIs of the current build to some "reference" baseline build or previous build